# Angular hostlistener for window:scroll firing twice; what is going on?

Tags: angular, typescript, scroll

So I am trying to set the positioning of table headers to match where they are (horizontally) when the page initially builds, to where they would be in a fixed position bar at the top of the page when you scroll down.

My strategy was to grab the offsetLeft attribute of each `<th>` in ngAfterViewInit, save them, and then use that later to set the left position of each explicitly when they are in the fixed bar and taken out of the context of the table (where the positioning would otherwise collapse).

The table has this structure:

```
<table>
    <thead [class.header-fixed]="isFixed" id="my-header">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col"><span>column title</span></th>
```

So in the top of the component I have:

```
private headerItems: number[] = [];
private fixedPosition: number; //set dynamically but can be set explicitly
public isFixed = false;
```

And this is ngAfterViewInit():

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    ...
    let header = document.getElementById('my-header');
    for (var i = 0; i < header.children[0].children.length; i++) {
        let headerItem = <HTMLElement> header.children[0].children[i]; 
        this.headerItems.push(headerItem.offsetLeft);
    }
    ...
}
```

And to capture the scroll:

```
@HostListener("window:scroll", ['$event']) onScroll($event) {

    const documentScrollTop = this.document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    let header = document.getElementById('my-header');
    ...
    if ((documentScrollTop > this.fixedPosition) && (!this.isFixed)) {
        this.isFixed = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < header.children[0].children.length; i++) {
            let headerItem = <HTMLElement> header.children[0].children[i];
            headerItem.style.left = this.headerItems[i].toString();
        }
    } else if ((this.isFixed) && (documentScrollTop < this.fixedPosition)) {
        this.isFixed = false;
    }
    ...
}
```

While this is not particularly Angularish, I don't think that's the cause of the problem. The intention here is to grab the left positions ONCE, then use them later repeatedly as necessary (there is some responsiveness impact, but I'm not worrying about that at the moment).

So essentially when I run this, what happens is that for every pixel scrolled, the event fires twice, and the code is run twice. The two events appear completely identical, and have the exact same timestamp. This isn't necessarily the problem (just odd), but the content of headerItems is weirdly different. On the first event, all the values are 0. In the second event, they are correct. Why is that happening when they are only set once? And in fact, initially `headerItems` is an empty array of no length, so it should never be filled with 0s. When I inspect `this`, there is only one `headerItems` array, so it's not getting duplicated somehow.

I've tried to only set the left positioning when the last item in the array has a value greater than 1 (so setting only when the values are correct, but that feels like a total hack), but that doesn't work, and I don't know why not. I'm not getting any errors.

What on Earth is going on here?